# nodejs express How to send to API not just request, but also a header

Tags: node.js, api, express

```
const api = supertest(app)
const newblog=await api.post({
   url: '/api/blogs',
headers: {authorization:"bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IjExMTEiLCJpZCI6IjVlZWFjMThkZmM3MDUzNzAwMGRkMjc4NCIsImlhdCI6MTU5MjQ0Mzk4NH0.D4TJ502z-eudWntUaPKneg3kaoS6iSfc2CVZdl7OcRs"}
   }).send({title: 'g',author: "b",url: "f",likes: 0}).expect(201)
```

it causes error
I can only send header and succees in Postman, but not in code. How to write correctly?

Answer (score 0):

supertest package explained, there is about setting a header and whatever
https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/398